# not able to configure zookeeper without persistence

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, apache-zookeeper, persistent-volumes

I am deploying kafka on a kube cluster. For that, I found bitnami chart that seems excellent.
I deploy the chat with this command

```
 helm install kafka-release bitnami/kafka  --set persistence.enabled=false
```

It seems that the charts considers the option persistence.enabled=false for kafka pods but not for  zookeeper one. The kafka pods are scheduled but not the zookeeper pod.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-248:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kafka-release-0                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          30s
kafka-release-zookeeper-0                      0/1     Pending            0          30s
```

In the documentation of bitnami kafka chart, I found no option to disable the persistance on the zookeeper pod level.
Could you help please
regards

Comment: I generally point people at Strimzi Kafka Operator rather than Helm Charts if you want to run a cluster in k8s.

Comment: How did you provision your cluster? What kubernetes version are you using? Please provide steps to recreate your issue. Running the command you provided got me:
```kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kafka-release-0             1/1     Running   2          2m42s
kafka-release-zookeeper-0   1/1     Running   0          2m42s``` so it seems fine.

Answer (score 3):

To configure zookeeper without persistence you can: `helm install kafka-release bitnami/kafka  --set persistence.enabled=false --set zookeeper.persistence.enabled=false`

Comment: resolved. Thank you